# Why does a child process of a shell script (or any process) inherit the standard input of its parent?

Tags: linux, file, shell, unix

I have a Bash script that gets invoked like this:

```
script.sh < input_file.txt
```

All script.sh does is run some other program:

```
#!/bin/bash
otherprogram
```

Now when "otherprogram" reads from stdin, it gets text from input_file.txt, without any need to explicitly redirect the standard input of script.sh into otherprogram.

I don't know a lot about how processes get started, but I have read that when fork() gets called, all file descriptors from the parent process, including stdin, are shared with the child--which makes sense, since fork() just makes an identical copy of everything in the parent process' memory. But why would all file descriptions still be shared after the child process replaces the copy of the parent with a new program (presumably by calling  exec...())?

If child processes do always inherit all file descriptors from their parent, can someone explain why that actually makes sense and is a good idea?

Comment: For a start if it did not then piping from one command to another would not work

Comment: The child process does _not_ replace the parent process. It is a child, the moment the child exits the parent is active again.

Comment: starting up a new app is a fork() as well. the shell forks itself, then in the child does an exec() call to replace itself with the binary of the new program. the parent continues on as it did before, shelling, while the child is no longer a shell, it's the user's desired program.

Comment: @arkascha: I think you've misinterpreted what the OP wrote. The OP's statement that "the child process replaces the copy of the parent with a new program" is quite right.

Comment: @ruakh Ah, now I understand the OPs statement. Indeed I was miss lead, thanks for pointing that out. However I would like to modify that statement: the child process _might_ replace the copy of the parent with a new program".

Answer (score 3):

When a fork is called () Most fields of the PCB (process control block) are copied from the original to the newly created PCB (and so also the open files, as you said).

To summarize, immediately after executing a fork:

- There are 2 processes that are exactly the same, except for the differences described in the fork(2) man page if you want to have a look.
- Both processes are at the same line of code (the line immediately after the fork).
- In the child process, the return value of the fork is 0.
- In the parent process, the return value of the fork is greater than 0.

Let's move to the exec:

So we now have two copies of the shell. But they are still both running the shell program; we want the child to run any program. The child uses exec, to replace itself with the the program you passes as argument. **Exec does not create a new process; it just changes the program file that an existing process is running.**

So exec first wipes out the memory state of the calling process. It then goes to the filesystem to find the program file requested and copies this file into the program's memory and initializes register state, including the PC.

**exec doesn't alter most of the other fields in the PCB - this is important, because it means the process calling exec can set things up if it wants to, for example changing the open files as in your case where the child copy inherit the the file descriptor of the stdin which is pointing to your input file.**

Another example can be:
You want that the child process when it prints on the standard output (2) for example by means of an echo, it actually prints on a file. What you can do is before calling the exec (father process) changing the place where the file descriptor 2 points to (using for example dup2()) and then call the fork() ad the exec in the child process.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the **Notes** in manpage of `fork()`? The notes says **Since version 2.3.3, rather than invoking the kernel's fork() system call, the glibc fork() wrapper that is provided as part of the NPTL threading implementation invokes clone(2) with flags that provide the same effect as the traditional system call**.

Comment: @alvits in order to reply to gesgsklw's answer it's not useful since he needs to understand the basics of forks and exec. One use of clone() is to implement threads: multiple threads of control in a program that run concurrently in a shared memory space. So i presonally prefer to leave fork() ad clone() separated also if in reality calling fork() corresponds to invoking clone() with specific flags.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix and related OSes, the general way to launch a program is:

- The process forks.
- The child process makes whatever changes to the environment are needed, such as (perhaps):

  - Changing where file descriptors point (especially stdin/stdout/stderr).
  - Changing the running user.
  - Changing the present working directory.
  - Changing/adding/removing environment variables. (Though you can also just do this as part of the next step.)
- The child process then replaces itself with the desired program.

This approach allows for a huge amount of flexibility; the parent program can decide exactly what should and should not be inherited. (It also fits well with the Unix philosophy, of doing one thing and doing it well: `exec` doesn't need 50 bajillion arguments for different things you might want the new program to have, because you just set those up in the process before switching over to that program.)

It also makes it very easy to write "wrapper" programs that delegate almost of all their functionality to other programs. For example, a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /directory/that/foo/requires/
foo "$@"
```

which is a drop-in replacement for `foo` that just changes the directory it's run in, doesn't have to worry about all the things that `foo` *should* inherit, only the one thing that it *shouldn't*. (Which, again, fits very well with the Unix philosophy.)